# Activate a Sencha function through a onChange on input=file

Tags: file, extjs, controller, touch, onchange

Sencha Touch does not support input type file so i am trying to do this with some html

```
config: {
    html: '<input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);">',
```

But i am only able to call functions outside of my app..

Does anybody know how i can call a controllerfunction?

Comment: Did u find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very pretty, but it is a workaround until this functionality is implemented in the Sencha Touch framework. This is code I use in my view file

```
config: {
    html: '<input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);">',
```

As soon as a file is chosen the function readURL is called. From this function I make a call to my application \ controller \ function \ with the following code

```
function readURL(input) { 
    window['myAppName'].app.getController('myControllerName').photoToStore(photo);
}
```

In the photoToStore function I get the base64 of the photo

```
photoToStore: function(photo) {
    var reader = new FileReader();      
    var img    = new Image();
    reader.readAsDataURL(photo.files[0]);                       

    reader.onload = function(e) {   
        img.src = e.target.result;                  
    }
}
```

In the final step I send the base64 sting to the backend and I am able to safe the photo as a file.